# como limitar informação de coluna sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

boa noite, em um script que utilizo adicionei esta string para obter uma certa informação,

```
<div class="col"><b><?= $this->lang->line('imei');?>:</b> <?=$db['custom_field'];?></div>
```

e o resultado é:

```
{"494d4549":"123456789098765"}
```

mas apenas pretendia apresentar 123456789098765

como posso limitar esta informação? obrigado.

Comment: Use `494d4549` chave no array.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e de um `print_r($db);` e coloque essa informação.]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito a pergunta, mas acho que o que procura é isto:

```
    <div class="col"><?=$db['custom_field'];?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, tente não usar as *short tags* do PHP, elas podem causar problemas, porque, dependendo do servidor onde você hospedar seu código-fonte, elas podem não ser aceitas.

Depois, você pode usar

```html
array_values() [protótipo: array array_values ( array $input )]
```

para pegar somente a chave associada aos valores do vetor (array).